# Can I just kill one process of PDF-XChange Viewer based on the opened document?

Tags: windows, pdf, tasks

I have multiple instances of PDF-XChange Viewer running. For example the english version of a document I am translating into german. When I compile a draft of the german version I have to close the PDF-XChange Viewer manually.

Is there an option for *taskkill* to close only one process of the program?

With *tasklist* I find out the PIDs of the instances but I have no clue which one is which one.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved a similar issue by keeping the Task Manager open, sorted by CPU usage, and then taking the Window I care about, picking it with the mouse, and moving it rapidly in circles (don't let go).

The CPU usage will jump up and the process related to the window you are moving around will be on or near the top of the list, easy to identify.

I understand that that is pretty manual and non-programmatically, but it works.

Comment: Well, in the task manager the title is displayed, there is no need to increase CPU usage to find that out. Interesting approach though... I need that from the command line.